# Rails connect to an 'external' sqlite database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, sqlite, external

I am trying to connect to a database from my rails app. This database is being updated all the time for storing the results of ongoing tests. My rails app is basically a front-end to display the test results.

What is the best way to access the sqlite database without interfering with the test framework? At the moment when I start the rails server it locks the database and no read/write is allowed to it while the server is running.

What is the best way to display results from a continuously growing database, where new records are not being added by the rails app itself? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider using another database engine, such as MySQL or Postgres. SQLite is a good RDBMS but does not fit well for high-concurrency scenarios. It has been designed mainly for desktop or device-embedded applications.

From http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html

> SQLite uses reader/writer locks on the entire database file. That
>   means if any process is reading from any part of the database, all
>   other processes are prevented from writing any other part of the
>   database. Similarly, if any one process is writing to the database,
>   all other processes are prevented from reading any other part of the
>   database.

Comment: I finally migrated to Postgres and it solved my problems, thanks for your reply Jef.